# Is it possible to send a keystroke like CMD V to a specific app from a sandboxed app?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

I would like to send a CMD V to a specific application. Let's say the foremost window of TextEdit.

Something like I would do in AppleScript

```
Tell "TextEdit"
  // paste from clipboard
end tell
```

I have this code:

```
class MyKeys {
  
  func send() {
    guard let sourceRef = CGEventSource(stateID: .combinedSessionState)
    else { return }
        
    let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: sourceRef,
                               virtualKey: 9,
                               keyDown: true)
    
    let commandControlMaskFlags = CGEventFlags(rawValue: CGEventFlags.maskCommand.rawValue)

    keyDownEvent?.flags = commandControlMaskFlags
    keyDownEvent?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
  }

}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      let myKeys = MyKeys()
      myKeys.send() // send CMD V
    }, label: {
      Text("paste")
    })
    .padding()
  }
}
```

This code works, but if the app that issues this command is open, and it has a text field which is focused, the clipboard will be pasted to the same application. Instead, I want the paste to be sent to the foremost window of TextEdit.

Is that possible for a sandboxed app to do that?

EDIT:

I have tried this variation to sent the keystroke directly to TextEdit PID. It does nothing:

```
func send() {
    let pid = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.TextEdit")
        
    guard let sourceRef = CGEventSource(stateID: .combinedSessionState),
          pid.count > 0
    else { return }
        
    let textEdit = pid.first
    guard let textEditPID = textEdit?.processIdentifier else { return }
    
    let keyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: sourceRef,
                               virtualKey: 9, // V
                               keyDown: true)
    
    let commandControlMaskFlags = CGEventFlags(rawValue: CGEventFlags.maskCommand.rawValue)

    keyDownEvent?.flags = commandControlMaskFlags
    keyDownEvent?.postToPid(textEditPID)
    
  }
```

Comment: I believe you'd have to have Accessibility permission granted

Comment: yes, I have but still I want to be able to send it to a specific running app.

Comment: One way is to create a CGEvent and post it to a specific `pid`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454804-posttopid I believe this can all be done in a sandbox, but not positive

Comment: I have modified the send function to send to PID. It does nothing. As usual, Apple has zero documentation on this.

Comment: Is Accessibility permission granted for your app?

Comment: yep. Accessibility granted. When I press the button macOS gives me a sound error. and the app is not sandboxed

Comment: Is TextEdit focused and a field the first responder?

Comment: does it matter? I am sending it to its PID. Please don't try to guess. Try the code.

Comment: Yes, it matters. Sending a CGEvent is basically the same as the main user taking an action. You can't paste into an app without it being focused and the field being first responder. Re: "Please don't try to guess. Try the code" I don't have the time to devote to spinning this up and trying it, but I'm happy to stop commenting if you don't want what insight I have.

Comment: yes it is focused but in order to click the button I have to focus the application I am developing.

Comment: Tell the code to focus the app first. Or, add a delay so that you can focus it.